# Showing that $f:\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 2\sum_{j=1}^\infty 3^{-j}x_j$ is an embedding

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let the function $f:\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x) = 2\sum_{j=1}^\infty 3^{-j}x_j$, where $x = (x_1, x_2,\dots)$ is some binary string. I am looking to understand a proof why this mapping is an embedding. Suppose that it is already argued that i.)  $f$ is an injection, ii.) $\forall x, y\in \{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}: x \neq y: |f(x) - f(y)| \geq 3^{-l}$, where $l$ is the first index where strings $x$ and $y$ differ, iii.) $f$ is continuous. Moreover, assume that is has already been proven that if $f:X\to Y$ is a mapping, then $f$ being continuous is equivalent to the fact that if $Y$ has a basis or subbasis, then the pre-image of each of the element of the basis (or subbasis) is open.

Then my reading material claims:

> Write $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}} = X$. Define $U_j = \{x \in X\mid x_j = 0\}, V_j = \{x \in X\mid x_j = 1\}$. These sets form a subbasis for the space $X$. Let $x \in U_j, y \in V_j$ and $l$ be the first index at which $x_l \neq y_l$. Note that $l \leq j$. Then $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq 3^{-l} \geq 3^{-j}$. Hence $(f(x) - 3^{-j}, f(x) + 3^{-j}) \cap f[X] \subset f[U_j]$. Thus $f[U_j]$ is an open subset of $f[X]$.

What I'm unsure about is why is the set $f[X]$ open? Is there some result stating that if $f:X\to Y$ is an injection and continuous, then then elements of the subbasis of $X$ are elements for the subbasis for $Y$, which would then (I guess) yield that $f[X]$ is open? Or is the argument that the set $f[U_j]$ is open in the relative topology of $f[X]$ in the real line $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last statement is "Thus $f[U_j]$ is an open subset of $f[X]$" which should be understood as "open in $f[X]$ with subspace topology on $f[X]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$".

The author doesn't claim  that $f[X]$ itself is open in $\mathbb{R}$. And in fact no continuous image of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ because $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is compact while $\mathbb{R}$ connected (but not compact).